# Why does math.pow throw OverflowError when x**y does not?

Tags: python, math

Per the documentation, the `math.pow` function operates as:

```
def pow(x, y):
    """
    pow(x, y)

    Return x**y (x to the power of y).
    """
    pass
```

I decided to mess around with large numbers, but I receive an error when I run this:

```
import math
calc = math.pow(1000, 103)
print(calc)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(math.pow(1000, 103))
OverflowError: math range error
```

However, the follow does not error:

```
calc = 1000 ** 103
print(calc)
>> (very large number)
```

If `math.pow` is suppose to function as `x**y`, why does it throw an `OverflowError` whereas explicitly doing `x**y` does not?

Comment: Could it be that you are using too big of numbers for the variables?

Comment: Try small integers for arguments; you'll see that `pow` returns an `int` while `math.pow` returns a `float`. The two are not entirely identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`math.pow` uses floating point which is limited to something about 1e308. If you require a function, use just `pow` or `operator.pow` (note those are not the same thing).

`operator.pow` is exactly the operation from `x ** y` while `pow` is a three-argument function to calculate `x ** y % z` where z can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

`math.pow` uses `C` complied code and the limit of `float` in `1.2E-38` to `3.4E+38` in `C`. Whenever, the result exceeds `3.4E+38`, it throws `OverflowError`.